# How to retrieve documents that are older than a specific ID?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a large collection of posts that are created by users. As the user scrolls down, I will load another 20 of these posts and push them to the page (like an infinite scroll).

To achieve this, I need to retrieve document that are older than the last posts ID that was loaded.

I'm using Mongoose in my app, so this is how I would write it:

```
Post.find({"_id": {"$gt": myLastId}}).limit(20).sort({"created": -1}).exec(function(err, posts) {...}
```

Although, logically, I can't see this working since all of my post IDs are GUIDs generated by Mongoose (such as `574c255db7fdb529fb38c5ab`).

I could use the `created` attribute (that defaults to `Date.now()` on creation), although what would happen on the rare occurrence when posts are created at the exact same time?

The only other way I can think of doing this is creating an `index` within the schema that interates up from 0, and I can find the next 20 posts that have an `index` older than the one passed. Is this a good approach, or is there a better method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with `{"_id": {"$gt": myLastId}}` is actually fine. MongoDB IDs encode the creation time, which is why this works. (See [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) and [this explanatory blog](https://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/12/20/querying-for-timestamps-using-objectids/).)

Adding an incremental index requires collection-level locks, so can be problematic for large numbers of writes.

Answer (score 0):

Treat it as any other paging function? i.e. keep a page index, a resultsPerPage variable, calculate how many to skip and update the page index after searching or clientside for the next request?

I don't use mongoose so here's a native example:

```
collection.find({}).limit(resultsPerPage).skip(resultsPerPage*(page-1))
```

Or something like this, you should get the idea. You should however try to avoid large skips but I don't think this question was about optimization.

Comment: What would happen if new `posts` were created during someone looking at the page though? For example, if they were looking at the first 20 results, wouldn't the second lot of 20 results contain `posts` from the first lot due to new `posts` being created?

Comment: Yes you're correct about that! I have seen this exact requirement mentioned in O'Reilly's 'MongoDB: The Definitive Guide' but I don't have it with me at work. If you're question wasn't answered by tonight I'll get back to you with the solution mentioned there.

Comment: Excuse me for not coming back to this yesterday. But the O'Reilly book pretty much suggest the exact approach as you currently have. Except that it uses an explicit sort on date, but I'm pretty sure the ObjectID is unique enough to never run into issues with your current code.